# Add columns in VBA macros if a specific header is available in the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

There are multiple columns with header "GOOD" like in cell A1, A2, A3.
IF "GOOD" is available then it should output me with new column for every "GOOD" Headed column besides it.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. See [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub InsertAfterGood()
Dim aHeaders As Variant
Dim i%

'For speed, parse the range of the headers as an array
aHeaders = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:Z1"))

'Loop through each intem in the array in reverse order, so the new columns you add on the way dosn't change the reference you will be using.
For i = UBound(aHeaders) To 1 Step -1
    If aHeaders(i, 1) = "good" Then
        Columns(i + 1).Insert
    End If
Next
End Sub
```